# AppDynamics support Opentracing

Tags: appdynamics, opentracing

I'm trying to determine if AppDyanmics support Opentracing. I've looked in the app dynamics site and stack overflow but can't find a clear answer.

Thanks,
Carlos

Answer (score 3):

From my current knowledge: no, AppDynamics doesn't support OpenTracing yet.

Usually, APM vendors have their own OpenTracing tracers build off the official specification and then get them listed at http://opentracing.io. But as of this writing there is no mention of any AppDynamics Tracers at https://opentracing.io/docs/supported-tracers/ nor https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/meta.

*Full disclosure: I work for Instana, a competitor that does support OpenTracing.*

Comment: AppDynamics now has opentracing support. https://docs.appdynamics.com/21.5/en/application-monitoring/configure-instrumentation/automatic-instrumentation-of-specialist-packages-frameworks/open-tracing-support

Answer (score 0):

No AppD doesn't support OpenTracing at this time. The question is why do you want this functionality when you can already extract custom data from transactions dynamically with most AppDynamics agents? Do you really want to hardcode your APM tool into your software application?

AppDynamics is building a unique way to support OpenTracing, which is currently in testing, but the approach is not by hardcoding libraries into the code. If you'd like to learn more please reach out to support, or you can contact me directly as I work for AppDynamics.

Thanks.